# How to find the sum of local maximas per day in Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, max, amazon-redshift

I have some numeric data with ascending time stamps, as follows:

```
amount | received_at
_______|______________
30     | 2016-11-18 10:21:35 AM
60     | 2016-11-18 10:22:05 AM
90     | 2016-11-18 10:22:35 AM
120    | 2016-11-18 10:23:05 AM
150    | 2016-11-18 10:23:35 AM
160    | 2016-11-18 10:24:05 AM
0      | 2016-11-18 10:26:00 AM
20     | 2016-11-18 10:26:20 AM
40     | 2016-11-18 10:26:40 AM
55     | 2016-11-18 10:26:50 AM
```

I need to add 160 and 55 to get the total number. This is not limited to only two numbers, but for a given group of columns, can be multiple such maximas that need to be added, on a daily basis. Is there a straightforward (enough) solution for this?

I'm using Redshift to calculate this number.

Comment: can you explain the logic in detail? should you find all the max values and add them before the amount becomes 0, for a day?

Comment: Not necessarily 0. It could drop to any value and pick up again, but we'd need to add the two (or more) highest numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your table is `create table t(amount int, received_at timestamptz);`

1) Stored function:

```
create function foo() returns setof t language plpgsql immutable as $$
declare
  r t;
  c t;
begin
  r := null;
  for c in (select * from t order by received_at) loop
    if r is null or r.amount < c.amount then
      r := c;
    else
      return next r;
      r := c;
    end if;
  end loop;
  if r is not null then
    return next r;
  end if;
end $$;

select * from foo();
```

2) Window function:

```
with cte as (
  select
    amount,
    received_at,
    case 
      when coalesce(lead(amount) over (order by received_at), 0) < amount then 1
      else 0 
    end as flag
  from t)
select amount, received_at from cte where flag = 1;
```

Result:

```
╔════════╤════════════════════════╗
║ amount │      received_at       ║
╠════════╪════════════════════════╣
║    160 │ 2016-11-18 10:24:05+02 ║
║     55 │ 2016-11-18 10:26:50+02 ║
╚════════╧════════════════════════╝
```

Disclaimer: I am not sure what you want to do at the day's crossing.

Comment: We don't know how we're going to handle midnight edge cases either truth be told :) But this is a start, and it looks like it works right. Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('day', received_at) order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Although this is the earlier answer, it only returned the MAX, and not multiple maximas. Abelisto's answer gives me what I'd want.

Comment: @CodingInCircles . . . If you want all maxes, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.  Your question is ambiguous about the presence of multiple maximas on a single day, and your sample data has no such examples.